# Modern GLSL basics

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I'm trying to learn the modern GLSL but i cant even display my a cube...

This is how i create VBO:

```
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboNormalHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);        

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboTextureHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

this is how i render vbo:

```
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPushAttrib(GL_TRANSFORM_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glTranslatef(0f, 0f, camera.zoom);

    glRotatef(camera.rotation.x, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(camera.rotation.y, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(camera.rotation.z, 0, 0, 1);

    glTranslatef(camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z);

    glPopAttrib();

    texture.bind();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexHandle);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboNormalHandle);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboTextureHandle);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 10f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, triangles.size() * 3);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);  
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    TextureImpl.bindNone();
```

if i dont use any shader programs or use something in the old glsl 120 everything renders fine, but when i use this program which should display my cube as i think, i get a black screen...

Vertex shader program:

```
#version 330

layout (std140) uniform Matrices {
    mat4 pvm;
} ;

in vec4 position;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = pvm * position ;
}
```

Fragment shader program:

```
#version 330

out vec4 outputF;

void main()
{
    outputF = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**What do i do wrong? Where can i find out how to do this basic stuff with the modern glsl?**

Comment: This is a quite good OpenGL/GLSL tutorial: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

Comment: Also, you try to mix up pre-3.0 OpenGL with 3.0 OpenGL quite horribly. You shouldn't use the global matrices provided by OpenGL functions (you should use uniform matrices), you shouldn't use client states, and shouldn't use standard materials.

Comment: yes, many people recoment it! I tried using it, but i still could not find how to render... :/

Comment: @Antonijn can you give me resources for that exactly, so i would not have to read other stuff?

Comment: @Antonijn also not all terms are clear for me. I dont really know what are global or uniform matrices, client states and standart materials. I also need a link with explanation about which part of opengl is that

Comment: I would strongly recommend you go through the arcsynthesis tutorial anyway, even if you can't render the examples. Once you understand all the definitions and all the technical stuff, you can easily follow the tutorials at the LWJGL wiki.

Comment: @antonijn the link "arcsynthesis.org/gltut" is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What we have here is a failure to communicate.

Consider this:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
```

OK. You're telling OpenGL that the position data is provided by some buffer object and that it has 3 floats per vertex. OK, fine.

How does OpenGL know that this position data is supposed to go to `position` in the vertex shader?

Answer: it doesn't.

`glVertexPointer` is a function that has been removed from GL 3.1+. It doesn't feed data to arbitrary vertex shader inputs; it feeds data to the removed vertex shader input `gl_Vertex`. This is hard-coded.

You should be [using generic vertex attributes](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification), generally through [`glVertexAttribPointer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glVertexAttribPointer) and [`glEnableVertexAttribArray`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glEnableVertexAttribArray). You should also be [using VAOs](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object).

Similarly, there is no way for OpenGL to know that you want it's removed matrix functions to feed data to the uniform `pvm`. Indeed, this is much worse, because you put that in [a uniform block](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Interface_Block#Buffer_backed). The data for a uniform block is supposed to come from a [user-provided *buffer object*](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object). Which you did not provide, and which OpenGL won't magically provide for you.

In short, you can't mix old-style OpenGL code with modern-style GLSL. You can use old-style GLSL (using `gl_Vertex` and `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix`), but then you're not using modern-style GLSL.